# How should I connect my new wifi smart switch to this wiring?

Tags: electrical

My switch controls a ceiling fan/light (with pull chain) combo.  I am trying to replace the switch with a Kasa HS200.  I pulled the switch out and saw a cluster of wires that don't make sense to me, particularly the 3 wires going into the switch, and the one ground wire connected with the black wire.

I've tested the voltages for each wire and found the following:

#3 = 120V
#2 = 15V
#1 = 0
#4 = 0

Can someone explain how this is working, and what I need to do to connet my smart switch?  Thanks.

PS. Ignore the actual loose connections on the screws. The breaker is off and I just attached it on there to show where the wires went.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If that is what was found at one switch, I would want the whole house checked before it burns down.  Never mind about wiring a new switch there, till you know the house is safe.

Comment: Where are the ground wires? It looks like they are switching neutral. Can you measure voltage between switch terminals and a reliable reference ground?

Comment: The connections on that switch are a nightmare. The aren't hooked properly and the one is actually looped _backward_. Make sure you have a firm understanding of the critical fundamentals of house wiring before proceeding. Poor connections are a fire risk.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the other boxes involved in this circuit please? Something is *extremely* wrong here

Comment: The connections were only loosely reconnected for the photo, but the breaker is off. All other switches at the house are properly wired and already switched to smart switches.  This is the only one left that stumped me.  This is the only switch in the room and it only controls the ceiling light/fan.  The wiring is a mess, yet the light/fan works normally when connected.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just having a black wire and ground connected is a big no-no.  Switch loops do use a white(marked with black) wire as hot with a black as switch hot, but you have two whites there with one connected to a black wire.  Even with the new information that the connections are just for show, the way they are connected requires much more information.  Will need to see how the fan/light wires are connected plus the power wires.

Comment: "Works normally" does not mean "properly wired".   There are some serious issues with the wiring in this photo, and if your only indication that other boxes don't have similar issues is that the lights all work normally, you should hire an electrician to inspect everything.

Answer (score -1):

From looking at and reading that the wires were just set back in place to show where they were...

From the looks of the device, where to plug the ground and neutral are obvious. The Live/Load I would assume would be left/right.

If you have the correct lengths of wire in the box, cut the tips of the wires at the insulation and restripe them. If you have any green wire, replace the black wire you have for the ground. Plug the live wire coming into the box on the center-left and the Load wire (to the light) into the center-right, then neutral far-left and ground far-right.

Answer (score -1):

IDK about your box but to wire the switch. 1 blk to blk line in. line in is power to the switch, 1 blk to blk load. load is what is going to receive the power when you flip the switch. all white neutral wires are wire nutted together and pushed to back of the box. Do the same with the ground wires bare from the house or green from fans and switches and such. turn the power back on and hopefully you got a smart switch.

side note there is no way that came out of the wall like that. if it did call a professional.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).